# requestAnimationFrame isn't working

Tags: javascript, animation

So I have this code where I want to make a simlpe animation, but I cant seem to figure out why it isnt working. I just want to play around with the animation, by changeing the circles radius.

```
function DrawCircle () {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasHeight, canvasWidth);
     ctx.beginPath();
     this.y = 200;

     this.circle_radius = 150;

    //Create circle
    ctx.arc(200, this.y, this.circle_radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle="#265D6D";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();


};

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var test = new DrawCircle();


function moving(test) {

    test.circle_radius =+ 50;


    window.requestAnimationFrame(moving);


};
moving(test);
```

Comment: *"isn't working"* - What is the expected behaviour, and what is the actual behaviour? Do you get any errors in the browser console? (Is the problem that your `moving()` function expects an argument that you are not passing to it? Try `window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { moving(test); })`.

Comment: Im simply trying to increase the circles radius, and nothing is happening

Comment: Well aside from the thing I mentioned before that would cause a runtime error, I just noticed you have `=+` in your `moving()` function: that should be `+=`. But aside from that, the only part of your code that does any drawing is in the `DrawCircle()` function, and you only call that function *once*. (Changing the value of `test.circle_radius` doesn't magically cause a redraw, so...)

Comment: i am passing the test object into my moving();?

Comment: Yes you are (assuming you made the change I suggested). But your `test` object doesn't have a method to redraw. It draws once, on instantiation.

Comment: instead of posting an answer I post a fiddle for your code that works and hope that you will take the time to have a look what I have changed to learn something: https://jsfiddle.net/93sq6Lcn/1/ (it's late)

Comment: Thanks wolfgang. I guess you my problem was that I created an object out from my drawing class, instead of keeping it like a function?